# Running JAVA EE application on Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, ubuntu

I have JAVA EE web app, written and tested on Windows (I used Tomcat server). I also have remote access to VirtualBox Machine where Ubuntu 14.04 is installed. I'd like to be able to run my app on this server and have access to it from my browser. I've installed there JAVA 7 and Tomcat 7. I'm getting access to the server by Putty using IP address and 1522 port. I copied my **.war** file to this server by **psftp** and then I copied it to

```
 /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps
```

folder.
I've checked what ports are open by this command:

```
>nc -zv IP_ADDRESS 80     
Connection to IP_ADDRESS 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

and I realized that 80 port is opened, so I've edited

```
/etc/tomcat7/server.xml
```

file and I changed port from **8080** to **80**. After that I still can't connect to the server. I'm typing in my browser:

```
IP_ADDRESS:80
```

and I get 404 error. What am I doing wrong? I have firewall disabled so it's not that.

@EDIT:
I'm starting Tomcat like that:

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop/start/restart
```

Comment: Does the URL match the name of the Dir in webapps?  Tomcat should've unzipped the *.war to a Dir within webapps

Comment: Can you access the Tomcat welcome page?

Comment: @Mecon
Tomcat unzipped *.war file, in webapps is new folder named the same as the *.war file. What correct url should be?

Comment: @Necreaux
No, I can't.

Comment: http://your-server:80/your-dir-name/

Comment: If I'm trying to reach this, then I get 404 error.

Comment: This may not a problem..  but I wanted point out that server.xml is usually inside a "conf" dir.   Example: /local/tomcat/conf/server.xml

Comment: @Mecon
Thanks, I've checked and this server.xml file also has changed port number.

Comment: create a dummy Dir under webapps called:  "xyz".

create a dummy text file called  index.html  right under the "xyz".
So it will be:   tomcat/webapps/xyz/index.html

This page's contents should be visible here:   http://ip-address:80/xyz/index.html

Comment: It would've been nice to see Tomcat Logs.      Also ..  execute  ps -ef | grep java  to check what tomcat you have running.   Its possible your tomcat didn't start because another WebServer (Tomcat) was already running..

Comment: [ps -ef log](http://pastebin.com/kxJgmbeL)

Comment: This may have info about the tomcat log files:  

java.util.logging.config.FILE=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties

Comment: I created "xyz" folder in webapps folder, and then `index.html` into it. I've restarted tomcat7 and it's still the same, 404 error.

Comment: @Mecon The file `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties` is empty.

Comment: try to do "wget" or "curl" from the machine itself?  That way you could test out the URL  with just "localhost", instead of "ip-address"    Because right now I really think your URL isn't reaching this tomcat..  maybe some other.

Comment: Is there a "log" Dir under this: /usr/share/tomcat7/   ?

Comment: @Mecon [/usr/share/tomcat7](http://pastebin.com/XznwETb5) and [wget](http://pastebin.com/XznwETb5) here is `permission denied` for index.html, maybe it's problem?

Comment: you posted wrong link for wget.  What do you get for wget

Comment: @Mecon sorry here is [old wget](http://pastebin.com/MKwwyeHK) then I did `var/lib/tomcat7/webapps$ sudo chmod 777 *` and now I get [new wget](http://pastebin.com/PuW8bTQe) but I still get 404 error.

Comment: I meant,  try to access the actual page you have. Example:
wget 156.17.42.126:80/xyz/index.html

And then:
wget localhost:80/xyz/index.html

Comment: @Mecon [wget responses](http://pastebin.com/LtscrTxN)

Comment: yeah. try a different port, or  try to prove its working by telnet

Comment: Port 80 is the only one I have opened.

Comment: You have two potential problems I can see that others have not mentioned. 1. If Tomcat is not running as the root user then it will not be able to open port 80 for accepting connections. This is a unix security feature. 2. There's a chance that your server already has Apache httpd running and listening on port 80.

Comment: @SteveC 1. I logged in as a root (I used `su` command) and I restarted the Tomcat server and it didn't help. 2. How to check it?

Comment: the fact that you're getting a 404 means something is listening to your port. Probably another instance of tomcat or apache httpd. You can find out using `lsof` or `netstat`.

Comment: @geert3 Did you mean `netstat -na` command? If so, here is the result: [link](http://pastebin.com/5Hq3em3M). There is probably nothing listening on 80 port.

Comment: You've run the netstat on the server where tomcat is running, right? According to your netstat output indeed nothing is listening on port 80 or 8080, so you cannot get http 404. You'd get connection refused or something like that. There is however a 8005 which is typical for tomcat. Can you post the `conf/server.xml` for tomcat?

Comment: @geert3 Yes, I run setstat on my remote server, where tomcat is running. Here is `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml` file, sorry I post it as a picture, but I don't know how to copy it. [LINK](http://i.imgur.com/nWdVaDQ.png)

Comment: If you started tomcat with `service tomcat7 start` then it will still be running as a non-root user. Doing this as `root` is no different to using `sudo`.

Comment: @SteveC I always run tomcat with `sudo service tomcat7 start` command.

Comment: Your `ps -ef log` above shows that tomcat is running as the `tomcat7` user. This user does not have permission to listen on port 80 for connections.

Comment: @SteveC How can I change it?

Comment: I found [THIS](http://askubuntu.com/a/527826/386431) post, that could be helpful for me, but I don't understand 2nd point. There is mentioned _Change the user and group in the file_, but should I change it to what user or group?